# Excel: how to do something like: select count(col3,col4,col5,col6,col7) from TBL where col2 = '1-Jan';

Tags: excel, count, multiple-columns, formulas

Currently, I'm using a complex countifs() statement:

```
=countifs($B$2:$B$B1000,"="&L7,'Sheet2'!$C$2:$C$1000,"*")+
 countifs($B$2:$B$B1000,"="&L7,'Sheet2'!$D$2:$D$1000,"*")+
 countifs($B$2:$B$B1000,"="&L7,'Sheet2'!$E$2:$E$1000,"*")+
 countifs($B$2:$B$B1000,"="&L7,'Sheet2'!$F$2:$F$1000,"*")+
 countifs($B$2:$B$B1000,"="&L7,'Sheet2'!$G$2:$G$1000,"*")
```

which is effectively performing a full table scan for each column and is ridiculously slow. There *has* to be a better way to do this! Suggestions?

What I'm trying to accomplish is counting the number of cells that have something in them for a given dates:

```
  date  |  Col1   |   Col2   |   Col3  |   Col4   |
---------------------------------------------------
  1-Jan |    A    |     A    |         |    A     |
  1-Jan |    A    |          |         |    A     |
  2-Jan |    A    |          |         |          |
  2-Jan |    A    |     A    |    A    |    A     |
  2-Jan |    A    |          |         |          |


   Day  |  Totals |
-------------------
  1-Jan |    5    |
  2-Jan |    6    |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it will be quicker.....but certainly shorter

=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B1000=L7)*(Sheet2!$C$2:$G$1000<>""))

Comment: This is awesome! It speeds up the process at least 1000 fold! Thanks!